# scrolltop not going to right element

Tags: jquery, css

I have div tags that are populated with rows (tr and td tags).  Users can add new rows dynamically and I append them (each of the list_content dept divs can have a variable number of rows within them so the size will change frequently):

```
$("#list_content_"+ dept_id).append(row);
```

After the row is appended, I want to scroll to the new row so they can see it (seeing is believing), but none of the different code has worked (they don't scroll to the right place). I either want the new row to be at the top of the screen, or just visible.  I'm not picky, I just want it to be consistent.

What hasn't worked:

```
$("#row_"+ id).animate({scrollTop: $("#row_"+ id).prop("scrollHeight")}, 2000);
```

OR

```
$("#list_content_"+ dept_id).scrollTop($("#list_content_"+ dept_id).scrollTop() + $("#row_" + id).position().top - $("#list_content_"+ dept_id).height()/2 + $("#row_" + id).height()/2);
```

OR

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#list_content_"+ dept_id).offset().top -80}, 2000);
```

OR

```
$("#list_content_"+ dept_id).animate({ scrollTop: $("#list_content_"+ dept_id).prop("scrollHeight")}, 2000);
```

Any help is appreciated!  Clearly, I'm not an expert on this.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: row.offset().top }, 2000);
```

Since you still hold a reference to the row, when appended you get it's coordinates when calling `.offset()`.

Comment: When I did row.offset().top, the page bombed.  This might be because the row variable has several hidden elements and spans inside a tr td tag.  Dunno.  When I did  $("#row_"+ id).offset().top instead, the page didn't bomb, but also didn't function as expected.

Comment: I would need to take a look at your page to know